# Implementing Weekly Scheduled Notifications at a Specific Time in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I have a Flutter app that currently displays a notification when a button at the center of the screen is pressed. I now want to enhance the notification functionality by implementing scheduled notifications to be triggered every Monday at 9:00 PM, based on the user's device timezone. Unlike the current button-triggered notifications, this scheduled notification should be independent of any button press and should automatically appear for users whose local time is Monday at 9:00 AM. I've provided my notification_service.dart file below as a reference for helpers. How can I modify this file to implement the desired weekly scheduled notifications accurately based on different timezones? Thanks in advance.

```
//notification_service.dart:

// This file will handle the setup and display of notifications.

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';


class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> init() async {
  var initializationSettingsAndroid = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  const initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
  );

  await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

  // Request notification permissions
  await _requestNotificationPermission();
}

Future<void> _requestNotificationPermission() async {
  if (await Permission.notification.request().isGranted) {
    // Permission is granted, you can show notifications.
  } else {
    // Permission is not granted, handle accordingly (e.g., show an explanation dialog).
  }
}

Future<void> showNotification() async {
  print("Attempting to show notification...");

  const androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'channel_id', // Change this to a unique channel ID
    'Channel Name', // Change this to a descriptive channel name
    // 'Channel Description', // Change this to a descriptive channel description, comment this line for flutter_local_notification ^9.0.0
    importance: Importance.high,
    priority: Priority.high,
  );
  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
  );

  try {
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, // Change this to a unique notification ID
      "This is a plain text notification",
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Custom Payload',
    );
    print("Notification displayed successfully!");
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error displaying notification: $e");
  }
}

  Future<void> onSelectNotification(String? payload) async {
    // Handle the tapped notification here (if needed).
  }
}
```